# how to store data from excel sheet into mysql database using jdbc connection

Tags: java, mysql, excel, jdbc

I have written the code for access data from Excel sheet but 
     i am not able to store into database using JDBC .
    my code for access data from excel sheet

```
   try{
    List list=new ArrayList();
    String fileName="d:\\menu.xls";
    File file=new File(fileName);
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  //int i=0;
 Iterator rows=sheet.rowIterator();
 while(rows.hasNext()){
     HSSFRow row=(HSSFRow)rows.next();
     System.out.println("\n");
     Iterator cells=row.cellIterator();
     while( cells.hasNext() ) {
         HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
         if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC==cell.getCellType()){
         System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+" " );
        // list.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());

         }
         else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==cell.getCellType()){
             System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+" " );
             //list.add(cell.getStringCellValue());

         }
         else
             if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN==cell.getCellType()){
             System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue()+" " );
             //list.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());

             }
             else
                 if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK==cell.getCellType()){
                     System.out.print( "BLANK     " );}
                     else
                 System.out.print("Unknown cell type");

     }

 }
System.out.println(list);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I got all the data into myeclipse console bt i have no idea how to store in DB

please tell me how to store data into mysql database using JDBC

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have an `ArrayList` in which you're adding cell values, you can proceed as follows:

```
public void insertRowInDB(List cellValues){
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try{            
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName?"
                                      + "user=sqlUser&password=sqlPassword");
         String sql = "INSERT INTO tableName(field1, field2, ..., fieldN) VALUES (?,?,...,?)";
         preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
         int paramIndex = 1;
         for(Object cell : cellValues){
             preparedStatement.setObject(paramIndex, cell);
             paramIndex++;
         }
         int status = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
         //DO something with the status if needed
    } catch(SQLException ex) { 
          /* log the exception */
    } finally {
        try{
            preparedStatemnt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch(SQLException ignored) {}
    }
}
```

You'll need make this little change:

```
while(rows.hasNext()){
    List list = new ArrayList(); // initialize the list here

    HSSFRow row=(HSSFRow)rows.next();
    System.out.println("\n");
    Iterator cells=row.cellIterator();
    while( cells.hasNext() ) {
        /* all your code seems fine here, just uncomment list.add(something) lines */
    }

    insertRowInDB(list); // insert the cells in your database
}
```

I also suggest you check out this [MySQL and Java JDBC - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html)

Comment: thanx a lot for your answer finally i got it !!

Comment: @AvinashSingh You're wellcome! :) If this worked for you please don't forget to accept the answer, so people looking for similar problems can identify this as useful. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Hi. I wanted to implement the same class and I've had an error: Invalid column index. The error indicates this part of code: `for(Object cell : cellValues){
             preparedStatement.setObject(paramIndex, cell);
             paramIndex++;
         }`     Can you help me, please?

Comment: Hi there. This error suggests the number of cells is != of the number of columns in your statement. Be aware that generally speaking indexes in Java start at `0` **BUT** when you work with `preparedStatement.setObject(index, object)` index starts at `1`. If you get stuck please post your new code and I'll try to help you. @RazvanN

Comment: Okay. I see what you're telling me. I wrote a sql query like this: `String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO STORE_LOCATIONS (ID, COUNTY, LOCALITY, STORE, STORE_NAME, ADDRESS, SCHEDULE, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";` how can we talk on the chat? I can't seem to access it right...

Comment: I did, I entered. I think a new chat room should be created :-?